# How to hide a form after being used? PHP

Tags: php

I realize this is quite easy with javascript, however for this problem, please avoid JS. The premise, I am creating a jeopardy board, and I cannot figure out how to hide the question once you've already clicked it from the gameboard. It sounds confusing, but I need the option to disappear once the form has been completed.
The following is my code for play.php.

```
<?PHP session_start();

$category1 = array("x", "x", "x", "x”", "x");
$answer1 = array("x", "x", "x", "x”", "x");

$category2 = array("x", "x", "x", "x”", "x");
$answer2 = array("x", "x", "x", "x”", "x");

$category3 = array("x", "x", "x", "x”", "x");
$answer3 = array("x", "x", "x", "x”", "x");

$category4 = array("x", "x", "x", "x”", "x");
$answer4 = array("x", "x", "x", "x”", "x");
$category5 = array("x", "x", "x", "x”", "x");
$answer5 = array("x", "x", "x", "x”", "x");

$_SESSION["Score"];
  
if (isset($_POST['q1'])){
  $_SESSION["Question"] = $category1[0];
  $_SESSION["Answer"] = $answer1[0];
  $_SESSION["Points"] = 100;
  header("Location: questionPage.php");
```

just the example of the first few questions. The next code is from play.php as well, running it.

```
<body>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="play.css" />
  </head>
  <style>

  </style>
  <form method="post">
    <div id="container">
      <table id="board">
        <tr id="categories">
...
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please see my notes below.  If it helps, great.  Otherwise, please [Edit] your question.  Please clarify *what* you need to "hide" (are your "questions" rows in an HTML table?), and exactly *when* you need to hide them (does the user click a "submit" button to refresh the page)?

Comment: You need to refactor this. You are repeating those arrays over and over which is a sure sign you need to rethink what you are doing here.  You should have a form input with a `qid` (or similar) vs numbering like `name="q1"`, `name="q2"`, etc. So it would be better if you did `name="qid" value="1"` Then you can do a lot more dynamic programming and removing a bunch of duplication and manual incremental variables. Anyway, bottom line is you probably are doing this programming very manually.

Answer (score 0):

To hide the table, I would recommend using CSS to "hide" your container. For example:

- Display container:

  ```
  <div id="container" style="display:block">
  ```
- Hide container:

  ```
  <div id="container" style="display:none">
  ```

You can easily do this with if/else in your "play.php".

Comment: I don't want to hide the whole gameboard, my goal is for only a block at a time to disappear as you go through it, answer question, and assign points.

Comment: OK: Same advice.  Put the parts you want to "hide" in a <div>, use a style="display" attribute, and show (display:block) or hide (display:none) as needed.  If every time you want to "hide" something you can refresh the page from the server, then you can do this in PHP (e.g. play.php).  Otherwise, if you're *NOT* redisplaying the page from the server, then you'll need to use Javascript.  Since you haven't told us exactly "how" or "when" you want to hide something, I can't give you any example code.  It's really very simple - but we need to know more details.

Answer (score 0):

In the below code, I am just checking whether the form is submitted or not. If It is submitted `$_POST['q1']` will be set and the form will disappear. Try like below,

```
<?php if(!isset($_POST['q1'])){ ?>
  <form method="post">
    <div id="container">
      <table id="board">
        <tr id="categories">
...
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </form>
<?php } ?>
```

But, Once you refresh the page. The form will appear again.